# Send sprop-parameter-sets inband rather than in SDP

Tags: ffmpeg, webrtc, h.264, rtp

I am trying to use ffmpeg to stream an MP4 file over rtp. I am sending the stream to a SFU server that will broadcast the stream to users. The clients are expecting to receive an h264 video stream with profile-level-id `42e01f`. The issue I'm having is that the video received by the clients does not decode properly (just a black screen). If I transcode the video before sending, then everything works correctly. If I dump the SDP that describes what ffmpeg is sending, there is a distinct difference between the transcoded and non-transcoded version.

For the non-transcoded version, my ffmpeg command looks like

```
ffmpeg  '-re' \
  '-v' \
  'info' \
  '-protocol_whitelist' \
  'pipe,tls,file,http,https,tcp,rtp' \
  '-i' \
  '-f' 'mp4' \
  'https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket/file' \
  '-map' \
  '0:v:0' \
  '-c:v' \
  'copy' \
  '-f' \
  'rtp' \
  '-sdp_file' 'out.sdp' \
  'rtp://142.93.14.110:40425?rtcpport=45155'
```

When I run this command, out.sdp contains the line

```
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z0LAH9kAUAW7AWoCAgKAAAH0gABdwAeMGSQ=,aMuMsg==; profile-level-id=42C01F
```

However, if I change `-c:v copy` to `-c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast`, then the sdp line changes to `a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;`. Given that there is no SDP exchange between ffmpeg and my SFU, I think the issue is that ffmpeg needs to be sending the sprops in-band rather than setting them in the sdp. Any help here would be amazing. The other possible issue is that the profile levels are sightly different.

Comment: Add `-bsf:v extract_extradata,dump_extra`

Answer (score 1):

A H.264 video stream always has metadata associated with it - called SPS and PPS. SPS/PPS can be in band or stored in the MP4 file or both.
The sprop-parameter-sets represents SPS and PPS BASE64 encoded and comma separated.
In your case a number of things can be wrong and I can only guess.

original MP4s don't have in band SPS/PPS (legal but may throw off your decode process)

original H.264 slightly out of spec

mismatch between inband SPS/PPS and MP4 SPS/PPS

incorrect implemented RTP/RTSP client of your SFU server

I assume that you want to avoid the transcode.
I would first check if SPS/PPS are in band in your source MP4.
If not - I would add SPS/PPS in band without transcoding.